# Problem diagnostic on Toyota Estima

Tags: toyota, obd-ii, hybrid, obd

In relation to my previous question: [Hybrid battery not charging fully](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/68816/hybrid-battery-not-charging-fully)

This morning I took the vehicle to the mechanic who has serviced all of my cars for the last 10 years.  He called me later in the day and said that they can't manage to read the diagnostics of the OBD-II port.  The diagnostic tool can read the basic stuff, but not the any of the hybrid/electric elements. He did say that the tool they are using can successfully read this data from a UK-sold Prius of the same year, therefore he suspects that Japanese original cars may have some other protocol and may require some other tools.

Is there anything special about the Japanese implementation of the OBD interface? What tools are necessary to read HV battery and charging information?